# How to plot data from CSV excel file

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to plot a line graph of two separate columns in a csv excel file using Python. The file contains 5 columns of details about movies that came out in 2016, which are: movie titles/release date/Distributor/Genre/MPAA/tickets sold.

In this particular scenario I'm trying to plot the release date and the number of tickets sold as a line graph and then find which month has the highest rate of tickets sold. [Here's some of the dataframe of the CSV file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpm0o.png) This is what I have so far but I'm not sure where to go from here, plus I keep running into a lot of errors. if anyone could help I'd appreciate it.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
headers = ['Tickets Sold','Release Date']
df = pd.read_csv('2016_movie_data.csv',names=headers)
print (df)

df['Release Date'] = df['Release Date'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
x = df['Release Date']
y = df['Tickets Sold']

# plot
plt.plot(x,y)
# beautify the x-labels
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Comment: It's best you take an example file, that just has a few lines and you post the exact erro, that you get with the code and the data that you posted here.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing **matplotlib.pyplot.plot** and use the this:

```
lines = df.plot.line(x, y)
```

by editing your last 3 lines of code